# Modify combobox to return NULL value

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I create one application for creating `Reports` and I find one mistake here.
When I run application Status is always selected as 0 and OrgUnitId as 0 and application return result in `Report` but in my store procedure I put condition if value are NULL it needs to return all data from database

```
USE [DesignSaoOsig1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TestReport]    Script Date: 17. 6. 2020. 08:31:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestReport]
(           
    @Status bit,
    @OrgJed int
) 
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
    FROM [DesignSaoOsig1].[dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
    WHERE (@Status IS NULL OR Status = @Status) AND (@OrgJed IS NULL OR OrgUnitID = @OrgJed)
END
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZTBx.png)

So I want to add in combobox's InitialValue which will be `Status` and `OrgUnitId` and when application is load It needs firstly show all records in `Report` but when user choose parameters it needs to filter.
So far here is my source code which I insert value to `combobox`

```
public void FillStatus()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM tblZaposleni_AD";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    using (SqlDataReader saReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (saReader.Read())
                        {
                            byte dbValue = saReader.GetByte(0);
                            string name = dbValue.ToString();
                            ddlStatus.Items.Add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

As well as another combobox

```
 public void FillOrgUnit()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT OrgUnitID FROM tblZaposleni_AD ORDER BY OrgUnitID ASC";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    using (SqlDataReader saReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (saReader.Read())
                        {
                            string name = saReader.GetInt64(0).ToString();
                            ddlOrgUnit.Items.Add(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And here is main function for filtering report

```
 private void GetReports(XtraReport report)
        {
            try
            {
                string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                string strproc = "TestReport";
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue;
                    sda.Fill(ds);

                    string[] arrvalues = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

                    for (int loopcounter = 0; loopcounter < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; loopcounter++)
                    {
                        //assign dataset values to array
                        arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["PrezimeIme"].ToString();
                        arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["NetworkLogin"].ToString();
                        arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["Status"].ToString();
                        arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["OrgUnitID"].ToString();
                    }


                    report.DataSource = ds;
                    report.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();


                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And here is Page_Load function which I use to load these two function as well as Load reports in combobox

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string path = @"\Reports\";
                CustomReportStorageWebExtension reportsStorage = new CustomReportStorageWebExtension(path);
                ddlReportName.DataSource = reportsStorage.GetUrls();
                ddlReportName.DataBind();

                //Call function for populate cb
                FillStatus();
                FillOrgUnit();
            }

            else
            {
                XtraReport reportToOpen = null;
                switch (ddlReportName.SelectedValue)
                {
                    case "Zaposleni 1":
                        reportToOpen = new ZaposleniSaoOsig1();
                        break;
                    case "Zaposleni 2":
                        reportToOpen = new ZaposleniSaoOsig2();
                        break;
                    case "Zaposleni 3":
                        reportToOpen = new ZaposleniSaoOsig3();
                        break;
                }
                GetReports(reportToOpen);
                ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(reportToOpen);                              
            }

        }
```

Comment: As a general comment.  Opening and closing a DB connection is VERY slow.  You should create a singleton class where you open a connection, store it and reuse it for the whole lifecycle of your Application, and close it.  Just make sure that your close it in all cases, including when exceptions occur and you exit normally & abnormally from the app.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Can you provide me some example ?

Comment: See https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton